# 'twisted' has no attribute '__version__'

Tags: python-3.x, twisted, autobahn

I have loaded twisted using pip `pip install twisted`. Then I tried to import `from autobahn.twisted.websocket import WebSocketClientProtocol`, I get error when I import `'twisted' has no attribute '__version__'`.

Answer (score 0):

`pip install --upgrade pyopenssl` can solve the issue when I am using Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use TLS functionality, use the appropriate extra:

```
pip install --upgrade twisted[tls]
```